# Unable to retrieve treeID after segmentation

Tags: lidr

I encountered a problem that `treeID` feature can not be retrieved after implementing `Dalponte2016()` chm-based segmentation method. The segmentation results can correctly show in multiple colors by using

```r
plot(las_res, bg = "white", size = 2, color = "treeID")
```

but these `treeID`s are actually not available (`NA`), and I cannot export the `treeID`s in both las/laz and .csv formats.

Comment: As I said yesterday, please show a minimal reproductible exemple. You are basically saying that *it works but it does not work*. We can't help you if you do not describe a  clear problem.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. In addition to JRR's comments, how are you accessing the treeID?